# ошибка при записи в бд SQLite

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite

System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: "SQL logic error
no such column: Цезарь"

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        string sql_command = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;"
            + "CREATE TABLE person("
          + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
          + "name TEXT, "
          + "sex TEXT, "
          + "age INTEGER, "
          + "salary INTEGER, "
          + "position TEXT, "
          + "place INTEGER);";

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            sql_command += "INSERT INTO person(name, sex, age, salary, position, place) "
                + "VALUES (" + workers_names[i] + ", " + people_gendar[i] +
                 ", " + age[i] + ", " + salary[i] + ", " + people_position[i] + ", " + place[i] + "); ";
        }

        cmd.CommandText = sql_command;
        Console.WriteLine(sql_command);
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: В чем вопрос? Что то не понятно в тексте ошибки?

Comment: выдаёт такую ошибку при добавлении массивом. К строчке присваивает все значения нормально. Если взять просто значения из массивов, то запишет без проблем

Comment: вы покажите содержимое результирущей `sql_command`, которая ошибка выдает

Comment: **НИКОГДА** не склеивайте значения в SQL через `+`! Используйте параметры для передачи вставляемых значений: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx